# R, macosx, Rscript Fatal error: creating temporary file for '-e' failed

Tags: r, rscript

I'm running R 3.6.0 on Mac osx 10.11.6 (El Capitan) and get an "Fatal error: creating temporary file for '-e' failed" error when calling Rscript via system().

```
test_cmd <- "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rscript -e 'print(\"Hello\")'"
system(test_cmd, intern = TRUE)
```

That returns this error:

```
[1] "Fatal error: creating temporary file for '-e' failed"
attr(,"status")
[1] 2
Warning message:
In system(test_cmd, intern = TRUE) :
  running command '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/Rscript -e 'print("Hello")'' had status 2
```

I get this error when trying to make a cluster via future, which led me to this specific example.

```
future::makeClusterPSOCK(1, outfile = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
```

That also calls Rscript and fails with the same error.

Also, if I call Rscript from the command line it runs fine.

Comment: Works without error with R 3.6.1 both in the Terminal and in R.app on macOS 10.14.6.

Answer (score 1):

I sorted it out - I had set the TMPDIR variable in my .REnviron file about a year ago while trying to fix something else I guess. That folder wasn't valid and was only used when a system call was ran. Upgrading R to 3.6.1 didn't fix this as that file stayed there.

Solution: delete the offending line in .REnviron in your home folder

Comment: Hi @leonfrench. I have the same issue. Could you be more specific on where the .REnviron file is and which line to delete? Thank you!